# Hi question is there anyway to do the RIGHT() function of excel in R studio?

Tags: r

Hi question is there anyway to do the RIGHT() function of excel in R studio?

in this data set it is also some imbalance which means that:
\ time
1 hhmm
2  hmm
3 hhmm

so some value is in the hhmm format as in 2000 for 20:00
please help so I can create
2 new column where it only contains the hh and the mm

Comment: It's really difficult to follow what you are asking for. Please see this to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610

Comment: If you use `stringr` library (which is part of `tidyverse`) you can get last `n` characters of a string with `str_sub(string, -n)`. I believe though that there are better ways to deal with your problem, but we would need you to provide us with a real data with `dput(head(yourdata))`.